# Power BI cumulative total not working in a matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get a series or cumuilative totals for sales across brands by hour using

```
Cumulative demand TY hour2 = CALCULATE(SUM('Actuals TY'[ConvertedRev]),FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Actuals TY'),'Actuals TY'[hourtime]<= max('Actuals TY'[hourtime])))
```

It works for the total but on for each brand it shows the total and not the amount for each brand, I presume there's something missing with filters but I'm not been able to work it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @James, Please be more descriptive and specific. Explain your intended result and share datasets as copiable text, not as image. Then I am sure people will react faster to your post. Stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ALLSELECTED('Actuals TY'[hourtime])` instead of `ALLSELECTED('Actuals TY')` because **ALLSELECTED()** without any columns mentioned uses the whole table context including all the *Brands* etc.

Comment: That's now showing the totals for each brand but now they aren't summing cumulatively

Comment: @James, can you show the structure of your matrix?

Comment: It's set up with Time in rows, brand in columns then demand TY, A forecast figure and last years amount, ![Here is what it looks like](https://imgur.com/a/mIyHV2O).